# setting --unlimited-quota-for-files flag in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm playing around with the file and filesystem api in html5 and apparently you need to have the --unlimited-quota-for-files flag turned on for it to work but I can't work out how this is done, can anyone tell me how to do this?

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Answer (score 1):

Just close Chrome and run it from command line like this

```
google-chrome --unlimited-quota-for-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, that was nearly there, you need to cd into the directory where chrome.exe lives and run: chrome --unlimited-quota-for-files